# Laravel + Vue - Delete object, but console returns error

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to successfully delete a record in vue. It deletes the records, but I get the following error in the console.

> 405 (Method Not Allowed)

I get this error in the network tab

> "exception": "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException",

This is in my .vue file.

```
  <button @click="deletePet(pet.id)">Delete</button>
```

This is my js file

```
methods: {
    deletePet(id){

        var petid = id;

        window.axios.delete('/client/pet/' + id)
        .then(response => this.onSubmitSuccess(response))
        .catch(error => this.onSubmitError(error));;

        console.log('Pet Id' + petid);
      }
    },
```

This is my laravel route

```
Route::delete('/client/pet/{id}', 'ClientController@deletePet')->name('client.pet.delete');
```

This is my method in the clientcontroller

```
public function deletePet($id){
      $pet = Pet::find($id);
      $pet->delete();

      return back();
    }
```

Comment: add this `this.axios.defaults.headers.common = {
          'X-CSRF-TOKEN': window.Laravel.csrfToken,
          'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
        };` before `window.axios.delete ...`

Comment: can you share what is going to your network tab with the request param

Comment: I get the following targetiing the line i added in - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaults' of undefined

Comment: try `window.axios.defaults....`

Comment: Do you have this route defined in a route group? If so, post the route group.  Did you verify the pet's id is being correctly appended to the url in the delete call?

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
        // rename myToken as you like
        window.myToken =  <?php echo json_encode([
            'csrfToken' => csrf_token(),
        ]); ?>
        </script>
    </head>
```

add common header :

```
 <script>
    window.axios.defaults.headers.common = {
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN' :  window.myToken 
    };
</script>
```

in your methods

```
methods: {
    deletePet(id){

        var petid = id;

        window.axios.delete('/client/pet/', {params:{'id': petid})
        .then(response => this.onSubmitSuccess(response))
        .catch(error => this.onSubmitError(error));;

        console.log('Pet Id' + petid);
      }
    },
```

laravel route :

```
Route::delete('client/pet/{id}', 'ClientController@deletePet')->name('client.pet.delete');
```